# Resumable download Google Drive API

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am using the Google Drive API to download files from Google Drive, it works fine, but I want to do more pause and resume functionality.

I read the instructions page of Google and found support for partial downloads (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads), they said "You can specify the portion of the file you want to dowload by using a byte range with the Range header", but I don't know how to do it, who can help me?

This is my code:

```cs
string fileId;
string path;
long bytes;
        private void DownloadWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            DriveService ds = GetService();
            var request = ds.Files.Get(fileId);

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += (Google.Apis.Download.IDownloadProgress progress) =>
                {
                    switch (progress.Status)
                    {
                        case Google.Apis.Download.DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                            {
                                bytes = progress.BytesDownloaded;
                                GoogleDrive.ReportProgress((int)bytes);
                                break;
                            }
                        case Google.Apis.Download.DownloadStatus.Completed:
                            {
                                SaveStream(stream);
                                break;
                            }
                        case Google.Apis.Download.DownloadStatus.Failed:
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                };
                request.Download(stream);

            }
        }
        private void DownloadWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
        }
        private void DownloadWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void SaveStream(MemoryStream stream)
        {
            long exlength = 0;
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
                exlength = fileInfo.Length;
            }
            var fileMode = exlength > 0 ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create;
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(path, fileMode, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                stream.WriteTo(file);
            }
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fileId = "1P2KckTacknNDsONttlzL4GPLSLldzCbA";
            path = "D:\\Data.zip";
            GoogleDrive.RunWorkerAsync();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already an answer similar to what you want to achieve here [1] but with an export request. Basically, after you get the request (and before you send it) you need to set the Range header as stated in the link you posted. For your case it would be like this:

```
DriveService ds = GetService(); 
var request = ds.Files.Get(fileId);
//Set the range header
request.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(from, to);
//More code…
//Send the request
request.Download(stream);
```

[1] [C# - Downloading from Google Drive in byte chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38449621)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, but I got an error in the line: ```request.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(from, to);```

Error CS1061: 'FilesResource.GetRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Headers' and no accessible extension method 'Headers' accepting a first argument of type 'FilesResource.GetRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: [1] has issues, as file downloaded is corrupt. see my comment on [1] post...