# Google Drive API V3 Out Of memory downloading large files

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api

I am having issues downloading large files over 1.5 GB from Google Drive using the .NET V3 nuGet package.

Using the code below:

```
public void DownloadFile(string fileId, string saveTo)
    {
        var request = service.Files.Get(fileId);
        var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        // Add a handler which will be notified on progress changes.
        // It will notify on each chunk download and when the
        // download is completed or failed.
        request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += (Google.Apis.Download.IDownloadProgress progress) =>
        {
            switch (progress.Status)
            {
                case Google.Apis.Download.DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                        break;
                    }
                case Google.Apis.Download.DownloadStatus.Completed:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                        SaveStream(stream, saveTo);
                        break;
                    }
                case Google.Apis.Download.DownloadStatus.Failed:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                        break;
                    }
            }
        };

        request.Download(stream);
        GC.Collect();
    }
    public void SaveStream(System.IO.MemoryStream stream, string saveTo)
    {
        using (System.IO.FileStream file = new System.IO.FileStream(saveTo, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
        {
            try
            {
                stream.WriteTo(file);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

I get an exception in Google.Apis.Download.IDownloadProgress:

Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Stack Trace is:

```
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Download.MediaDownloader.<DownloadCoreAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
```

The console output looks something like this:

```
.
.
.

1310720000
1321205760
1331691520
1342177280
Download failed.
```

It generally fails around the same point in terms of number of bytes downloaded.

Is there any way to either use partial download, or resume download?  I can't find much documentation or examples.  I can't seem to access request.MediaDownloader.Range to set that.  I do not see any way to set a range header.  I tried playing around with chunksizes to no avail.

Comment: This is an interesting question and not one i have run into before. YOu might want to cross post it over on the library https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38449621/c-sharp-downloading-from-google-drive-in-byte-chunks   // also in https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/media_download  there is reference to `progress.BytesDownloaded` - maybe that can help too?

Comment: I am looping the BytesDownloaded inthe code above.  That is the output.  I cannot seem to access the Range header.  I can't find any concrete example of of downloading in chunks using the MediaDownloader functionality in the Google API.

Comment: In the stack question I linked there is reference to `var request = exportRequest.CreateRequest(); request.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(from, to);` - does that not work?

Comment: I stopped using Memory Stream and instead used file stream, and the code worked after that.  I was able to explicitly cast as MediaDownloader to get the Range value, but it was still going out of memory after 1.2 - 1.3 GB of the download.

So, what I did was switch the MemoryStream to a FileStream.  I wrote the stream to disk instead of buffering.  It left me with an issue where I could now download 5 or 6 files straight through (at about 3-4 GB each) before it would hang.  This was remedied by flushing and closing the FileStream after each download.

I will formally answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after consulting with someone from the GitHub thread [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1747) I was able to use a FileStream instead of a MemoryStream and I got the 4GB file to download successfully.

This lead to another issue where I would be able to download 5 or 6 files straight, then the program would hang on the 7th file.  The remedy I found for this was to .Flush() and .Close() the FileStream after each download.  After I did that, I was able to download 20+ files straight through, 3/4 GB each in size (these are .ISO image files).

```
public void DownloadFile(string fileId, string saveTo)
    {
        var request = service.Files.Get(fileId);
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(saveTo, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        // Add a handler which will be notified on progress changes.
        // It will notify on each chunk download and when the
        // download is completed or failed.   
        request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += (Google.Apis.Download.IDownloadProgress progress) =>
        {
            switch (progress.Status)
            {
                case Google.Apis.Download.DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                        break;
                    }
                case Google.Apis.Download.DownloadStatus.Completed:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                        fileStream.Flush();
                        fileStream.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                case Google.Apis.Download.DownloadStatus.Failed:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                        break;
                    }
            }
        };
        request.Download(fileStream);
    }
```